# Python mutagen not saving correctly

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, mutagen

I am pulling text from an Excel document and adding them as id3 tags to some mp3 files. Most of the characters in my Excel document are Russian (Unicode) but some are in English. When I run the script, all the English tags get written as meta data correctly, but all the Russian characters show up as question marks. If I print the Russian characters in my console, they show up perfectly. Why are they getting written as question marks?

### Python

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
import xlrd
import glob
import re
import os
for name in glob.glob('*.mp3'):
  audio = EasyID3(name)
  wb = xlrd.open_workbook('xl.xls')
  sh = wb.sheet_by_name(u'Russian')
  col_b = 1
  col_c = 2
  col_e = 4
  col_g = 6
  col_i = 8
  col_k = 10
  for i in range(sh.nrows):
    row = sh.row_values(i)
    for j in range(len(row)):
      if row[j] == name:
        audio["title"] = sh.cell(i,col_e).value
        audio["author"] = sh.cell(i,col_i).value
        audio["copyright"] = sh.cell(i,col_g).value
        audio["album"] = sh.cell(i,col_k).value
        audio["discsubtitle"] = sh.cell(i,col_c).value
        audio.save()
print "All MP3 MetaData Parsed!"
```

Comment: Although not pertinent to your Unicode issue you're currently having, you're iterating through your entire Excel workbook for every MP3 that you have in your folder, and considering the fact you have a straight match between your column and filename I would just iterate through the Excel workbook and for each row check if the file exists based on the filename in your workbook.

Comment: Are you sure that the program you use to read the tags after running your scripts can handle unicode?

Comment: Im just moving the mp3 files to a windows machine and trying to view the tags in "details" under "properties"

Comment: I thought it might be because the package was using ID3v1 rather than ID3v2 (as far as I know ID3v1 doesn't support extended character sets/encodings/whatever), but looking through the source for [`mutagen.easyid3`](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/source/browse/trunk/mutagen/easyid3.py?r=93) and the module it wraps, [`mutagen.id3`](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/source/browse/trunk/mutagen/id3.py?r=93), it seems the `EasyID3` class is designed to properly encode characters outside the ASCII range. So I'm not sure what your issue is, unless the fault lies in how `xlrd` handles nonASCIIchars.

Comment: If I print the value of lets say "sh.cell(i,col_e).value" in the console, The russian characters all show up normally. I even tried to give "audio["title"]" a literal value of "КАК ВСЕ НАЧИНАЛОСЬ
" and I get this error: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file mp3.py on line 21, but no encoding declared` I then included `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of my script, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use 'decode' or/and 'encode' methods.

The great answer about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/370199/1321404

anoter way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4631545/1321404