# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, mako

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 537: ordinal not in range(128), referer: ...
```

I always get this error when I try to output my whole website with characters "č". I am using mako templating. What to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, UnicodeDecodeError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766669/python-unicodedecodeerror)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error occurs because somewhere code coerces your unicode template string into a python 2 `str`; you need to encode the rendered template into an UTF-8 bytestring yourself:

```
if isinstance(rendered, unicode):
    rendered = rendered.encode('UTF-8')

# rendered is now guaranteed to be of type str
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code cannot decode some of characters because of being more than 8 bits so try to use this:

```
converted = unicode("your_string", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
```

Good luck

Comment: Unfortunately this is the exact opposite of what OP needs to do.

Comment: I'm afraid dear Antti. I think I wrote the solution belonged to the answer exactly. He wants his code to skip the Unicode which is more than one byte and this is the exact solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running your script with the right locale settings, e.g.

```
$ locale -a | grep "^en_.\+UTF-8"
en_GB.UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Docs: `man locale`, `man setlocale`.

For Linux, also install a language pack, e.g. `sudo apt-get install language-pack-en`.

Answer (score -1):

You can replace your special characters č with this code: č

```
"your string".replace('č','&#269;')
```

if you are working on a web site u can create a sanytize function for all the special characters.