# Unable to get a sha256 hash of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I'm trying to get a hash of a string:

```py
hs = hashlib.sha256(get_some_string()).hexdigest()
```

...but I get an error:

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877589/python-unicode-utf-8 might help you

Answer (score 50):

Use `utf-8` encoding:

```
hs = hashlib.sha256(get_some_string().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

To get more information read [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes).